# Clear date field in cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an HTML input field which is rendered as

```
<input id="dateId"
  placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
  type="date"
  pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
>
```

I would like to run a test in cypress (v3.1.0) to enter data into the field and later clear the field. I am able to enter data into the field. However, when I try to clear the field cypress throws an error.

```
cy.get('#dateId').type('2018-12-16');
// Save and reload
cy.get('#dateId').should('have.value', '2018-12-16');
// Some more testing

cy.get('#dateId').clear();
```

> CypressError: Typing into a date input with cy.type() requires a valid date with the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. You passed: {selectall}{del}

How can I clear this input field?

Comment: I don't know the library, but can't it be that it starts the month from 0? so you have an invalid month?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/2793) and was released in Cypress [3.1.5](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-1-5)

---

Cypress's [`.clear()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear.html) command is an alias for `.type({selectall}{backspace})`. [Typing on a date input](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Date-Inputs) is subject to some [validation code](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/e46edab964c96b725ec55597b27cbf94eec18df6/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/actions/type.coffee#L120-L128) which can only take a specific date string.

The workaround is to change the element value. This can be done by invoking the jQuery [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) command.

```
cy.get('#dateInput').invoke('val', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me.

`cy.get('.date_of_birth .date-picker input').type('01/06/1992')
 cy.get(".date_of_birth .date-picker input").should("have.value", "01/06/1992")
 cy.get(".date_of_birth .date-picker input").clear()`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Looks like my issue was fixed with the 3.1.5 release!

Answer (score -1):

```
cy.get('#dateId').click().clear().type('2018-12-16');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cy.get("className").type("{selectall}{backspace}").type("date").type("{enter}")
```